# Not getting all value from left table using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am joining 3 tables to fetch the values but I need all record from left table will be fetched and matched value from other table will come. I am providing my query below.

```
SELECT *
FROM cb_vechile_category
LEFT JOIN cb_service_rental_tariff ON cb_service_rental_tariff.cat_id = cb_vechile_category.cat_id
INNER JOIN cb_rental_service_type ON cb_service_rental_tariff.rental_type = cb_rental_service_type.id
WHERE cb_service_rental_tariff.city_code =1
AND cb_service_rental_tariff.ride_id =1
AND cb_service_rental_tariff.rental_type =10
ORDER BY cb_service_rental_tariff.tariff_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here I need all record from `cb_vechile_category` table will come and matched value from form other tables will be fetched. If any record from `cb_vechile_category` will not matched with others the values will remain blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your condition in ON Clause instead of where

```
SELECT *
FROM cb_vechile_category
LEFT JOIN 
(select * from cb_service_rental_tariff 
inner JOIN cb_rental_service_type ON cb_service_rental_tariff.rental_type = 
cb_rental_service_type.id 
where cb_service_rental_tariff.city_code =1
AND cb_service_rental_tariff.ride_id =1
AND cb_service_rental_tariff.rental_type =10)A ON A.cat_id = cb_vechile_category.cat_id 
order by A.tariff_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Its giving wrong result. Its fetching all value rather than the conditions.